# Launch Screen Image Stretches in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, launch-screen

I'm hoping I can get some help explaining why this is happening. I have been working on switching my app I've been learning / building from UIKit to SwitfUI since this seems to be the future... plus it's fun to learn.

I've got my plist setup with the background and image
[image]

And the very first time I run it when the simulator opens or I clear and erase the simulator is this:
[image]

However, every time after I run the app, the image stretches.
[image]

When I try it on my phone, it seems to stretch every time. I'm not sure what is happening here. Is it just that SwiftUI needs more work or is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Nothing yet, sorry

Comment: Been having this issue a lot too, happens more on the Simulator than the device.

Comment: This is happening to me, i think it´s a common issue, did someone solve it?

Comment: Still happening..

Answer (score 25):

This seems to be a SwiftUI Bug, which still isn't fixed. The only way to go around this bug is to go back to storyboards.

You have to create a launch screen storyboard and link it to your project.

**To do so:**

- create a new file (cmd + n) and select launch screen
- customize your launch screen inside the new storyboard (don't use SVG format for images)
- go to your project settings -> "General" and select the launch screen file as your “Launch Screen File”, which creates a new entry in your info.plist
- remove your old SwiftUI launch screen entries in info.plist

Comment: I'm still getting this intermittently but don't want to switch to pngs.  I've just tried adding "px" to my SVG's width and height (first line of file) which previously had no units.  I will try and remember to come back here if the problem reoccurs or if it seems gone for good.

Comment: The blog post link is broken

Comment: I agree that a Storyboard is still necessary even for an otherwise pure SwiftUI app. The problem to me is that the Boolean `UIImageRespectsSafeAreaInsets` isn't enough to tell the SVG how to behave. For `UIImageView` you can choose `Scale To Fill`, `Aspect Fit`, `Aspect Fill`, `Center`, `Top Left`, and others. Why doesn't Xcode provide these same keys in `info.plist` to tell the SVG how to behave when you're not using a Storyboard?

Answer (score 6):

I'll mention this because it technically worked for me.

Turn off the device. Turn it on again. Reinstall the app. Launch screen is not stretched anymore!

It's a strange behavior and it makes me wonder if it's a bug with iOS and not with swiftui.

I got this answer from a comment on this [article](https://danielbernal.co/stretched-launch-screen-images-in-swiftui-the-fix/#comment-156).

Comment: Worked for me. :facepalm:

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `.svg` images for the launch screen (works on device).

1. In assets, select the image (in list) and select the image (in detail).
2. Shows the inspector (button on the top right).
3. In the Resizing option, check Preserve Vector Data.
4. In the Scales option, select Single Scale.

I hope it will be useful, to this recurring question and even today with Xcode 14 it is not really solved.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: SVG or PDF, preserve vector data, single scale... still doesn't work after all these years. It's a shame that we still have to resort to storyboards.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't notice it immediately. It seems the original launch screen was still pulled from a cache at first.

Answer (score 2):

Resize your image to @1x, @2x, and @3x versions when @1x is 200x200px.

Then upload it to Assets folder and change info.plist `Image Name`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the same issue with changing the dimensions of SVG.

1. Select the Launch image from the assets and press the "Space" button.
2. Open with Subline Text.
3. Change width & Height ( I give the dimensions of iPhone 12 pro in px , initially it was 100%)

<svg width="390px" height="844px" viewBox="0 0 1500 1500"

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

1. In the attributes inspector check "Preserve Vector Data"
2. In Scales select "Single Scale"

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or we can just use Launch Screen Interface, add key and value below into your plist.

**Key**

```
Launch screen interface file base name or UILaunchStoryboardName
```

**Value**

```
Our Launch Screen Name
```

**Example**

[image]

Using LaunchScreen Storyboard will expand the limitation of our customization as well.